# Why does this diagram commute by uniqueness of the maps?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, diagram-chasing

I do not understand the following remark from the lecture:

> Consider two field $L$ and $K$. We know that there exist unique(!) ring homomorphisms $f_K: \mathbb{Z} \rightarrow K$ and  $f_L: \mathbb{Z} \rightarrow L$ and let $g: K \rightarrow L$ a field homomorphism. Then by uniqueness of $f_K$ and $f_L$ we have $g \circ f_K(a) = f_L(a)$ for all $a \in \mathbb{Z}$.
>
> **Remark**: My definition of ring homomorphism from the lecture requires $f(1) = 1$, which is the reason of the uniqueness of $f_K$ and $f_L$.

I do not understand why $g \circ f_K(a) = f_L(a)$ should hold, could you please explain this to me?

Comment: Unique means only one: since both $g\circ f_K$ and $f_L$ are ring homomorphisms $\Bbb Z\to L$, they coincide.

Comment: @Berci: Thanks a lot, I got it now.

Comment: @Berci your comment looks like an answer to me